# Install MSI files at single Installation

Tags: windows, windows-installer

I have to install two MSI files. Are any way to install both one as dependences of the other?

Is It possible or there are any tool to generate a new MSI that trigger the boths one previous the other ?

I mean, I have

```
MSIinstallerONE.msi 
MSIinstallerTWO.msi
```

At the end I need to execute

```
msiexec /i MSIINstallerALL.msi
```

And allow to uninstall (if it is possible too)

```
msiexec /x MSIINstallerALL.msi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you could create a chained package, i.e. a main MSI package in which you add as chained packages your two MSI packages. Most of the tools used for setup authoring support this, you just need to decide on the tool you like the most:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

Answer (score 0):

use iepress

go to Start Menu

Then

Run 
and write
iexpress
then hit enter

follow instruction in the wizard